# Axios - how to get value from nth object

Tags: response

I have a response like below:

```
response = 
[
 {
   "location":{
       some data
   },
   "library":[
      {
          "id": 1234,
          "name": "CCT"
      },
      {
          "id": 3546,
          "name": "KAT"
      },
      {
          "id": 6577,
         "name": "LLC"
      },
   ]
  }
]
```

No I would like to get value `id=3546`.

When I do something like

`response.data[0].library[0].id` then I get `id=1234`

but how to retrieve value from the second or third object, please?

I tried:

```
response.data[0].library[0].id(1)
```

or

```
response.data[0].library[0].id.get(1)
```

but it's not a right solution :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go: :)

```
response.data[0].library[1].id

response.data[0].library[0] -> first element in the library object
response.data[0].library[1] -> second element in the library object
response.data[0].library[2] -> third element in the library object
```

Comment: Ahhh, yeah, that was silly question  :) 
Thank you :)